# Selenium not working with Internet Explorer on Remote Machine unless logged in and focused on screen

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I am running Selenium(WebDriver) tests on remote machines using Jenkins and Selenium Grid 2. Everything works great with Chrome but I'm having an issue with Internet Explorer(go figure). When I kick off the Jenkins job that runs the IE tests, if I am not logged into the remote machine and watching the tests they all fail. When I have the remote machine pulled up on my desktop using Remote Desktop Connection and I watch the tests then they all pass with no problems. I really don't know what's going on here. The point of using Jenkins and Selenium Grid is so anyone can kick these tests off and I don't have to be involved. Now someone has to be logged into the remote machine for the tests to work. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: It's a configuration issue. What user does Jenkins log in as?

Comment: I don't think Jenkins logs in as any user. I can run the tests fine using Chrome and not being logged into the node.

Comment: Tested this again this morning. Ran the chrome tests and they all passed with no problems. The IE tests opened the browser and navigated to the log in page. WebDriver would not fill in the log in form until I remoted into the node machine. Then the tests executed successfully.

Comment: I should add that I am using the Selenium Grid plugin for Jenkins.